# Finding extrema of $x^2y^2+2xy^2+y^4$ on $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\ |\ |x|\le 2, |y|\le 2\}$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow\mathbb R$ be defined by $f(x,y)=x^2y^2+2xy^2+y^4$ and the region $D\subset\mathbb R^2$ by $D=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\ |\ |x|\le 2, |y|\le 2\}$. I have to find the extrema of $f$ on $D$ and I have to concider wether the found extrema are global or local.

I already have found that 
$\nabla f=\vec{0}$ for $(x,0)$ if $x\in\mathbb R$ and $(-1,\pm\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2})$  and that $f(x,y)=0$ for $(x,0)$, $x\in\mathbb R$ and for $(x,\pm\sqrt{-x^2-2x})$ for $-2<x<0$.

I guess I have to do something with the level curve $N_0=f^{-1}(\{0\})$ and the fact that the complement of this set consists of path-connected sets on which $f(x,y)\ne0$, therefore $f$ is either strictly positive or strictly negative on these sets (every set can have one of the two options separately). However, I do not know if this approach will get me anywhere and I was wondering if anyone could help me solve this problem (another way).

Please note that this exercise comes in an introductory real-analysis course so I'm not too familiar with very advanced math.

Comment: You can't solve it the calculus way, yet you set the gradient to zero to find the critical points?

Comment: Yeah I guess you're right. I kind of put that part there so that, hopefully, I wouldn't get answers that were too "simple". I guess it is too vague, though. I'll just remove it.

Comment: What is the context of this question? Is it from a book in multivariate calculus?

Comment: It is from a hand-out of an introductory course in real analysis.

Comment: I would just do it the calculus way if possible. Find the extrema inside the square, plug in the values and see what you get. Get a function of one variable on the edges and find the extrema along each edge. Then look at your list and see where the absolute extrema are. For the local extrema you can use the second derivative test.

Comment: Have you covered the hessian matrix and/or lagrange multipliers?

Comment: @JonathanDavidson I have not and to be honest I have no idea what those are. I'm also pretty sure that's not the way we are required to solve this problem, since my hand-out doesn't even mention those things.

Comment: Why would this problem have anything to do with the level curve $f=0$?

Comment: @Jack I'm not sure. That's pretty much the only tool (aside from reasoning) that is being used in my lecture notes to find (global) extrema, so I thought that it could be used in this problem as well.

Answer (score 1):

Since

$$ f(x,y)=[(x+1)^2+y^2-1]y^2 $$

we know that the $f(x,y)=0$ iff $(x,y)$ lies on $y=0$ or on the circle $(x+1)^2+y^2=1$. $f(x,y)<0$ iff $(x,y)$ lies in the interior of the circle $(x+1)^2+y^2=1$.

Of the four critical points $(0,0),(-2,0),(-1,\frac{2}{2}),(-1,-\frac{2}{2})$ the first two lie on $f^{-1}(0)$ and the second two line in a connected component of its complement. The boundary points of the $4\times4$ square, with the exception of the point $(-2,0)$ also lie in a connected component of the complement of $f^{-1}(0)$.

[image: Level curves]

Comment: Do you mean $(x+1)^2+y^2=1$ instead of $(x-1)^2+y^2=1$ and $(-1,\pm\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})$ instead of $(-1,\pm\frac{2}{2})$? Also, do you only concider $(-2,0)$ out of the critical points $(x,0)$ because it is on the boundary? What does the position of the critical points say about them in terms of extrema?

Comment: Yes, thanks, that's a typo. I will correct it

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2y^2+2xy^2+y^4\leq2^2\cdot2^2+2\cdot2\cdot2^2+2^4=48$$
and it's obvious that it's a maximal value.

If $x=-1$ and $y=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ then we get a value $-\frac{1}{4}$.

But $$x^2y^2+2xy^2+y^4+\frac{1}{4}=x^2y^2+2xy^2+y^2+y^4-y^2+\frac{1}{4}=$$
$$=y^2(x+1)^2+\left(y^2-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\geq0,$$
which says that $-\frac{1}{4}$ it's a minimal value.

Comment: That would give the maximum but not the minimum.

Comment: @CoffeeBlis I fixed my post. See now.

Comment: Looks good. I think the question is also asking for relative minima and maxima though. For that the "multivariable calculus" way really is best.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, find the critical points for $f$ in the *interior* of $D$:
$$
C=\{(x,0)\mid |x|<2\}\cup\{(-1,\pm\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})\}.
$$
The place where you find the min and max of $f$ should be $C$ together with the boundary $\partial D$.

Now, on the set $C$ we have,
$$
f(x,0)=0,\quad f(-1,\pm\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})=\frac{1}{2}(1-2+\frac{1}{2})=-\frac{1}{4}.
$$
On each side (the *closed* segament) of the boundary of $D$, the function is a function of single variable; so you can find the min and max on it.

Eventually, put all the results above together to give the answer.

Comment: Why should the min/max be on the boundary $\partial D$? Or are you saying that if they were anywhere, they would be on the boundary or on $C$? If so, still, why the boundary?

Comment: I'm not saying that it *should* be on the boundary. The boundary is the *possible* place where $f$ obtains its min/max.

Comment: Alright, thanks! Then again, why specifically check the boundary? For instance, it is clear to me why the critical points should be checked, but not so with the boundary.

Comment: The critical points only tell you information about the interior of $D$. But you are looking for the min/max of $f$ on $D$. So the boundary must be checked.